# Python2.7: Compare within DataFrame groups and filter based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which i plan to group by 'name', 'driverRef', 'tyre' and filter only groups which have similar values in one column.

Within the group, all rows have the same value in that column.

<strike>Similar is defined as at most a range of 3 in difference between values. eg. if the unique numbers in the column are 5, 10, 12, 13, only groups with 10,12,13 are kept.</strike>

EDIT: The similarity criteria i planned originally is ambiguous, i have changed it to simply the mode of the group.

```
    name                   driverRef stint  tyre      lap   stint length     
0   Australian Grand Prix   ham     1.0     Super soft  1    5      
1   Australian Grand Prix   vettel  1.0     Super soft  2    10       
2   Australian Grand Prix   bottas  1.0     Super soft  3    10      
3   Australian Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  20   13        
4   Australian Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  21   13  
5   Australian Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  22   13  
6   Bahrain Grand Prix   ham     1.0     Super soft  1    5      
7   Bahrain Grand Prix   vettel  1.0     Super soft  2    6       
8   Bahrain Grand Prix   bottas  1.0     Super soft  3    6      
9   Bahrain Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  20   13        
10  Bahrain Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  21   13  
11  Bahrain Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  22   13
```

Expected output:

```
    name                   driverRef stint  tyre      lap   stint length         

4   Australian Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  21   13  
5   Australian Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  22   13  
9   Bahrain Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  20   13        
10  Bahrain Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  21   13  
11  Bahrain Grand Prix   alonso  2.0     Super soft  22   13
```

Comment: there might be a little ambiguity on the last part - what if the values are `10, 12, 20, 22` ?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Yeah, i realized that. I will adjust the "similar" criteria, to simply the mode of the group

Comment: @doyz - Do you need groupby by  `'name', 'driverRef', 'tyre'` or by `'name', 'tyre'` ? What is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
s = df.groupby(['name','tyre'])['stint length'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
#alternative
#s=df.groupby(['name','tyre'])['stint length'].transform(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])

df = df[df['stint length'] == s]
print (df)
                     name driverRef  stint        tyre  lap  stint length
3   Australian Grand Prix    alonso    2.0  Super soft   20            13
4   Australian Grand Prix    alonso    2.0  Super soft   21            13
5   Australian Grand Prix    alonso    2.0  Super soft   22            13
9      Bahrain Grand Prix    alonso    2.0  Super soft   20            13
10     Bahrain Grand Prix    alonso    2.0  Super soft   21            13
11     Bahrain Grand Prix    alonso    2.0  Super soft   22            13
```